# How to install brotli from pip, when anaconda requires brotlipy

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have an environment from anaconda, which includes among others, `scipy`. The anaconda dependencies require the library `brotlipy` for `scipy` (`conda install brotlipy`). This is unfortunate because I require the google-provided `brotli` package itself (`pip install brotli`). This is because the google bindings support a newer version of the brotli algorithm, with support for chunk-wise compression.

I can install brotli with `pip` inside my environment (so that I have both packages side-by-side, `brotlipy` for `scipy`, and `brotli` for myself). However, a simple import statement will always refer to the brotlipy:

```
import brotli
brotli
Out[4]: <module 'brotli' from 'C:\\Users\\x\\.conda\\envs\\myenv3\\lib\\site-packages\\brotli\\__init__.py'>
brotli.Compressor().process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\.conda\envs\myenv3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3397, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-121c31e74b28>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    brotli.Compressor().process
AttributeError: 'Compressor' object has no attribute 'process'
```

(Since it doesn't have support `__version__`, I'm calling to `.process` to test whether I'm calling the right version of `brotli`, which should yield

```
brotli.Compressor().process
Out[5]: <function Compressor.process>
```

---

How can I force Python to load the correct brotli?

---

Here is me attempting to remove `brotlipy`, which leads to a removal of scipy.

```
> conda remove brotlipy -n myenv3
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done




## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\x\.conda\envs\myenv3

  removed specs:
    - brotlipy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    bottleneck-1.3.5           |   py38h080aedc_0         106 KB
    colorama-0.4.6             |   py38haa95532_0          32 KB
    freetype-2.12.1            |       ha860e81_0         490 KB
    giflib-5.2.1               |       h8cc25b3_3          88 KB
    glib-2.69.1                |       h5dc1a3c_2         1.8 MB
    gst-plugins-base-1.18.5    |       h9e645db_0         1.7 MB
    gstreamer-1.18.5           |       hd78058f_0         1.7 MB
    jpeg-9e                    |       h2bbff1b_1         320 KB
    kiwisolver-1.4.4           |   py38hd77b12b_0          60 KB
    krb5-1.19.4                |       h5b6d351_0         786 KB
    lerc-3.0                   |       hd77b12b_0         120 KB
    libclang-14.0.6            |default_hb5a9fac_1         154 KB
    libclang13-14.0.6          |default_h8e68704_1        22.5 MB
    libdeflate-1.17            |       h2bbff1b_0         151 KB
    libffi-3.4.4               |       hd77b12b_0         113 KB
    libiconv-1.16              |       h2bbff1b_2         651 KB
    libogg-1.3.5               |       h2bbff1b_1          33 KB
    libpng-1.6.39              |       h8cc25b3_0         369 KB
    libtiff-4.5.0              |       h6c2663c_2         1.2 MB
    libvorbis-1.3.7            |       he774522_0         202 KB
    libwebp-1.2.4              |       hbc33d0d_1          73 KB
    libwebp-base-1.2.4         |       h2bbff1b_1         304 KB
    libxml2-2.10.3             |       h0ad7f3c_0         2.9 MB
    libxslt-1.1.37             |       h2bbff1b_0         448 KB
    lz4-c-1.9.4                |       h2bbff1b_0         143 KB
    matplotlib-inline-0.1.6    |   py38haa95532_0          17 KB
    numexpr-2.8.4              |   py38h5b0cc5e_0         127 KB
    packaging-23.0             |   py38haa95532_0          69 KB
    pcre-8.45                  |       hd77b12b_0         382 KB
    pillow-9.4.0               |   py38hd77b12b_0        1015 KB
    ply-3.11                   |           py38_0          81 KB
    prompt-toolkit-3.0.36      |   py38haa95532_0         566 KB
    pygments-2.15.1            |   py38haa95532_1         1.7 MB
    pyparsing-3.0.9            |   py38haa95532_0         152 KB
    pyqt-5.15.7                |   py38hd77b12b_0         3.7 MB
    pyqt5-sip-12.11.0          |   py38hd77b12b_0          75 KB
    pytz-2022.7                |   py38haa95532_0         210 KB
    qt-main-5.15.2             |       he8e5bd7_8        59.4 MB
    qt-webengine-5.15.9        |       hb9a9bb5_5        48.9 MB
    qtwebkit-5.212             |       h2bbfb41_5        11.6 MB
    setuptools-67.8.0          |   py38haa95532_0         1.0 MB
    sip-6.6.2                  |   py38hd77b12b_0         434 KB
    sqlite-3.41.2              |       h2bbff1b_0         894 KB
    tbb-2021.8.0               |       h59b6b97_0         149 KB
    tk-8.6.12                  |       h2bbff1b_0         3.1 MB
    toml-0.10.2                |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          20 KB
    tornado-6.2                |   py38h2bbff1b_0         609 KB
    traitlets-5.7.1            |   py38haa95532_0         205 KB
    wheel-0.38.4               |   py38haa95532_0          83 KB
    xz-5.4.2                   |       h8cc25b3_0         592 KB
    zlib-1.2.13                |       h8cc25b3_0         113 KB
    zstd-1.5.5                 |       hd43e919_0         682 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       172.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  giflib             pkgs/main/win-64::giflib-5.2.1-h8cc25b3_3
  glib               pkgs/main/win-64::glib-2.69.1-h5dc1a3c_2
  gst-plugins-base   pkgs/main/win-64::gst-plugins-base-1.18.5-h9e645db_0
  gstreamer          pkgs/main/win-64::gstreamer-1.18.5-hd78058f_0
  krb5               pkgs/main/win-64::krb5-1.19.4-h5b6d351_0
  lerc               pkgs/main/win-64::lerc-3.0-hd77b12b_0
  libclang           pkgs/main/win-64::libclang-14.0.6-default_hb5a9fac_1
  libclang13         pkgs/main/win-64::libclang13-14.0.6-default_h8e68704_1
  libdeflate         pkgs/main/win-64::libdeflate-1.17-h2bbff1b_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/win-64::libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_0
  libiconv           pkgs/main/win-64::libiconv-1.16-h2bbff1b_2
  libogg             pkgs/main/win-64::libogg-1.3.5-h2bbff1b_1
  libvorbis          pkgs/main/win-64::libvorbis-1.3.7-he774522_0
  libwebp-base       pkgs/main/win-64::libwebp-base-1.2.4-h2bbff1b_1
  libxml2            pkgs/main/win-64::libxml2-2.10.3-h0ad7f3c_0
  libxslt            pkgs/main/win-64::libxslt-1.1.37-h2bbff1b_0
  pcre               pkgs/main/win-64::pcre-8.45-hd77b12b_0
  ply                pkgs/main/win-64::ply-3.11-py38_0
  pyqt5-sip          pkgs/main/win-64::pyqt5-sip-12.11.0-py38hd77b12b_0
  qt-main            pkgs/main/win-64::qt-main-5.15.2-he8e5bd7_8
  qt-webengine       pkgs/main/win-64::qt-webengine-5.15.9-hb9a9bb5_5
  qtwebkit           pkgs/main/win-64::qtwebkit-5.212-h2bbfb41_5
  toml               pkgs/main/noarch::toml-0.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  appdirs-1.4.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  brotlipy-0.7.0-py38h294d835_1004
  cffi-1.15.1-py38hd8c33c5_0
  charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  cryptography-39.0.1-py38h21b164f_0
  icc_rt-2022.1.0-h6049295_2
  idna-3.4-py38haa95532_0
  patsy-0.5.2-py38haa95532_1
  pooch-1.4.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pycparser-2.21-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pyopenssl-23.0.0-py38haa95532_0
  pysocks-1.7.1-py38haa95532_0
  python_abi-3.8-2_cp38
  qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
  requests-2.28.1-py38haa95532_1
  scipy-1.10.0-py38h321e85e_1
  seaborn-0.11.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  statsmodels-0.13.2-py38h2bbff1b_0
  urllib3-1.26.14-py38haa95532_0
  win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py38haa95532_0
  wincertstore-0.2-py38haa95532_2

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  bottleneck                           1.3.4-py38h080aedc_0 --> 1.3.5-py38h080aedc_0
  colorama           pkgs/main/noarch::colorama-0.4.4-pyhd~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::colorama-0.4.6-py38haa95532_0
  freetype                                2.10.4-hd328e21_0 --> 2.12.1-ha860e81_0
  jpeg                                        9e-h2bbff1b_0 --> 9e-h2bbff1b_1
  kiwisolver                           1.3.2-py38hd77b12b_0 --> 1.4.4-py38hd77b12b_0
  libpng                                  1.6.37-h2a8f88b_0 --> 1.6.39-h8cc25b3_0
  libtiff                                  4.2.0-hd0e1b90_0 --> 4.5.0-h6c2663c_2
  libwebp                                  1.2.2-h2bbff1b_0 --> 1.2.4-hbc33d0d_1
  lz4-c                                    1.9.3-h2bbff1b_1 --> 1.9.4-h2bbff1b_0
  matplotlib-inline  pkgs/main/noarch::matplotlib-inline-0~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-inline-0.1.6-py38haa95532_0
  numexpr                              2.8.1-py38hb80d3ca_0 --> 2.8.4-py38h5b0cc5e_0
  packaging          pkgs/main/noarch::packaging-21.3-pyhd~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::packaging-23.0-py38haa95532_0
  pillow                               9.0.1-py38hdc2b20a_0 --> 9.4.0-py38hd77b12b_0
  prompt-toolkit     pkgs/main/noarch::prompt-toolkit-3.0.~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::prompt-toolkit-3.0.36-py38haa95532_0
  pygments           pkgs/main/noarch::pygments-2.11.2-pyh~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::pygments-2.15.1-py38haa95532_1
  pyparsing          pkgs/main/noarch::pyparsing-3.0.4-pyh~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::pyparsing-3.0.9-py38haa95532_0
  pyqt                                 5.9.2-py38hd77b12b_6 --> 5.15.7-py38hd77b12b_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/noarch::pytz-2021.3-pyhd3eb~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::pytz-2022.7-py38haa95532_0
  setuptools                          61.2.0-py38haa95532_0 --> 67.8.0-py38haa95532_0
  sip                                4.19.13-py38hd77b12b_0 --> 6.6.2-py38hd77b12b_0
  sqlite                                  3.38.3-h2bbff1b_0 --> 3.41.2-h2bbff1b_0
  tbb                                   2021.5.0-h59b6b97_0 --> 2021.8.0-h59b6b97_0
  tk                                      8.6.11-h2bbff1b_1 --> 8.6.12-h2bbff1b_0
  tornado                                6.1-py38h2bbff1b_0 --> 6.2-py38h2bbff1b_0
  traitlets          pkgs/main/noarch::traitlets-5.1.1-pyh~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::traitlets-5.7.1-py38haa95532_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.37.1-pyhd3e~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.38.4-py38haa95532_0
  xz                                       5.2.5-h8cc25b3_1 --> 5.4.2-h8cc25b3_0
  zlib                                    1.2.12-h8cc25b3_2 --> 1.2.13-h8cc25b3_0
  zstd                                     1.4.9-h19a0ad4_0 --> 1.5.5-hd43e919_0
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are referring to? One is from `pip isntall brotli`, the other `conda install brotlipy`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller this is correct, I specified.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce, but when I create an empty env and install `scipy`, then only `brotli` is installed, not `brotlipy`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I also had no problems on my linux installations. I'm suspecting an issue with my windows setup -- I can paste the log soon when I'm at that machine again.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce your issue, but on my windows machine, `brotlipy` is not installed as a `scipy` dependency. What are your python version and scipy requirements?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I added my attempt to remove brotlipy to the question. I am on Python 3.8 (would updating Python fix this?). I don't think that I set any specific requirements for scipy (note that conda doesn't downgrade scipy but rather uninstalls it altogether. Any installation of scipy also brings back brotlipy).

Comment: If you install scipy from `conda-forge` then it does not have `brotlipy` as a dependency. So if you `conda remove brotlipy` and `conda install -c conda-forge scipy` I think you should be able to just do `pip install brotli` and have a clean setup

Comment: @FlyingTeller this fixed my underlying issue. I rephrased the question so that this works better as an answer, would happy to accept your comment if you posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be worth to try to fix the underlying issue of having to different `brotli.py` that python might find when doing `import brotli`.

since you do want the `pip` installed version, I would try to remove `brotlipy` from your conda env. As you have noted, that will also remove `scipy`. However, this only seems to be valid for the version installed from default channels. If you install `scipy` from conda-forge, `brotlipy` will not be installed

So you could do

```
conda remove brotlipy #this will also remove scipy
conda install -c conda-forge scipy # pick up scipy version that will not install brotlipy
```

With this, you should now only have your `pip` installed version in `site-packages` and no more ambiguous imports